# Check if post is added manually or through wp_insert_post()

Tags: wp-insert-post, save-post

I might not be thinking this right but here is my situation:

- I have a custom post type called `events`.
- Some of my events are imported from an API and inserted through `wp_insert_post()` (in a plugin), some are added manually in the admin edit screen.
- On post saving I need to add some informations to the `post_meta` but **only if the post is added manually (through the admin edit screen)**.

So I am hooking into `save_post_events` and performing some security checks but I have no idea how to check if the request is only coming from the admin edit page because right now the `save_post` action triggers also if the post is added with the `wp_insert_post` function.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You can add a small metabox with checkbox file like Is it Adding manually? when you will add a event from Dashboard, you will check this checkbox. Next you will use get_post_meta function and get this checkbox value. if it is on then you get the post ID, otherwise you will leave it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution without adding any other metaboxes. I haven't thought about it but the import function in my plugin uses a `nonce` so I just check if my nonce is set or not.

Here is my `save_post_events` function:

```
add_action( 'save_post_events', 'wse_327066_example', 10, 3);
function wse_327066_example( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
  if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE || $post->post_status == 'trash' || !current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) || isset( $_POST['_import_nonce'] ) ) 
    return;

  # Now I can do whatever I want with posts saved from the admin edit screen... 
}
```